# Can't remove virtual host on Mac

Tags: macos, apache, localhost, virtualhost, host

I have set a virtual host some time ago.

I have set that when I go to vaarkamp.it it show the localhost folder. Now I want to remove that setting.

I've gone to my host file to delete the host entry but that doesn't exist.

My host file in etc/ looks like this at the moment:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

Just the normal host file...

But the url vaarkamp.it still goes to my localhost at 127.0.0.1.
I've executed a traceroute command in the terminal and this is the outcome.

```
 traceroute to vaarkamp.it (127.0.0.1), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
  1  localhost (127.0.0.1)  0.235 ms  0.043 ms  0.035 ms
```

Is there anyway I can remove this routing without reinstalling macOS?

Sytem: macOS Sierra version 10.12.4(16E195)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like [vaarkamp.it](http://vaarkamp.it) redirects to localhost.
So on your end everything is fine, but the website itself redirects back to localhost.